# I'm a bit lost: how to render rails/ruby on a website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, centos

Ok, long time php guy doing my best to pick up ruby on rails by developing a small website for myself using only ror instead of php.

However i'm a bit stuck, and i think it is because i'm not exactly understanding how rails actually works.

I am running centos 5.5 / apache2. I have successfully installed ruby, rubygems, and subsequently rails and passenger. All these are 'working', i can run ruby commands, gem commands etc.

But how do I start using rails on my website? If I create an .erb or .rb file with some simple ruby commands, it just displays as plain text when I navigate to it.

Do I need to configure apache to 'execute' .rb or .erb files (similar to the way .php files execute?).

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: You have to make a rails project to start with rails. A (very quickly) tutorial is here: http://rubyonrails.org/download. You dont need to run apache etc if you have a development server. You can run it with the standard rails webserver and sqlite database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Blender mentioned, rails comes with an in build web server called webrick. (Think of it same as apache .. for now)

so all you have to do is go to the rails project directory, and run the command

if you are using rails < 3.x

```
ruby script/server
```

if you are using rails > 3.x

```
rails server
```

once u done this your rails project will start in webrick server and by default in port 3000

```
http://localhost:3000
```

you may consider apache/ some other rails server setup for production deployment, but to get started you dont need apache at all

and welcome to ruby world ! :D

HTH

sameera

Comment: Thank you sameera! This is the the issue I was facing... I was trying to use script/server on rails > 3.x... using rails sever solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the Rails Getting Started Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Ahh ok things are starting to click. I created a project, and have it working as expected when I navigate to the folder. I am assuming now the only thing left to do is reconfigure apache to point to my rails application rather than the regular var/www/html/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to really get a handle on Rails and what it is first. This site has some great information for beginners, and should help you understand what you are working with and your next steps to get an application running:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I've also heard some good things about the information here:

http://railsforzombies.org/

Comment: Thanks ctcherry! Things are starting to click, I did actually get my rails app working via navigating to it. And you are right... I'm completely stuck in PHP land, but i'm starting to get moving in the right direction now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read a huge tutorial on this topic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Ruby is the language, and Ruby on Rails is a framework. From the guide:

> Rails is a web application development
>   framework written in the Ruby
>   language. It is designed to make
>   programming web applications easier by
>   making assumptions about what every
>   developer needs to get started. It
>   allows you to write less code while
>   accomplishing more than many other
>   languages and frameworks. Experienced
>   Rails developers also report that it
>   makes web application development more
>   fun.

I'd read Chapter 4, if you already know all this, as it talks about the actual webserver.

Rails comes with it's own webserver, so Apache isn't needed.

Comment: hmm... that is interesting. I have been trying to get rails to work 'inside' apache, but clearly this isn't the case. I think i'm getting closer though.

Comment: As you are developing with rails you don't have to use apache. But when you deploy it live, you WILL want to use apache or another web server to be "in front" of Rails. Thats what passenger does for example, it allows apache to run your Rails application almost automatically. But again, as you are just starting to develop your Rails application you don't need to use those tools, because you can use the build in rails web server.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) for getting started in Rails.